# New data frame, if specific value(s) is contained AND other values aren't included in a range of columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

So, I have a large data frame with monthly observations of n individuals.

```
ind y_0101 y_0102 y_0103 y_0104_ .... y_0311 y_0312
 A    33      6      1      2            1      5   
 B    36      5      0      2            1      5   
 C    22      4      1      NA           1      5   
 D    2       2      0      2            1      5   
 E    5       2      1      2            1      6   
 F    7       1      0      2            1      5   
 G    8       6      1      2            1      5   
 H    2       8      0      2            2      5   
 I    1       3      1      2            1      5   
 J    3       2      0      2            1      5
```

I want to create a new data frame, in which include the individuals who meet some specific conditions.
E.g. if, for individual i, the range of column y_0101:y_0312 does NOT include values of 3 & 6 & NA, AND include values of 2 | 1 THEN for individual i should be included in new data frame. Which produce the following data frame:

```
ind y_0101 y_0102 y_0103 y_0104_ .... y_0311 y_0312
 B    36      5      0      2            1      5
 D    2       2      0      2            1      5       
 F    7       1      0      2            1      5   
 H    2       8      0      2            2      5
```

I tried different ways, but I can't figure out how to get multiple conditions included.

```
df <- df %>% filter(vars(starts_with("y_"))!=3 | !=6 | != NA)
```

or

```
df <- df %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("y_")), all_vars(!=3 | !=6 | != NA)
```

I've tried some other things as well, like `!%in%`, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `rowSums` :

```
cols <- grep('y_', names(df))
include <- c(1, 2)
not_include <- c(3, 6, NA)

result <- subset(df, rowSums(sapply(df[cols], `%in%`, include)) > 0 & 
                     rowSums(sapply(df[cols], `%in%`, not_include)) == 0)
result

#  ind y_0101 y_0102 y_0103 y_0104 y_0311 y_0312
#2   B     36      5      0      2      1      5
#4   D      2      2      0      2      1      5
#6   F      7      1      0      2      1      5
#8   H      2      8      0      2      2      5
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ind = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J"), y_0101 = c(33L, 36L, 22L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 
3L), y_0102 = c(6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 2L), y_0103 = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), y_0104 = c(2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), y_0311 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), y_0312 = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're almost there, but might need a slight shift in the logic:

```
df <- data.frame(A1 = 1:10,
                 A2 = 10:1,
                 A3 = 1:10,
                 B1 = 1:10)
df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("A")), ~!(.x %in% c(3, 6, NA))) %>% 
  filter(if_any(starts_with("A"), ~ .x %in% c(1, 2)))
```

In the first step, I filter out all rows where any of the columns are 3, 6, or NA. In the second row, I filter down to only rows where at least one of the columns is 1 or 2. Does this help with your case?